# flutter date time picker to add start and end dates

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]
I read about date time picker in flutter docs but its only supports selecting one day and display it 
but what I want is to select a start date and an end date to display results between these dates

anyone can help me how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `date_range_picker`.

Install it:

```
  date_range_picker: ^1.0.3
```

And use like this:

```
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRagePicker;
...
new MaterialButton(
    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    onPressed: () async {
      final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
          initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()).add(new Duration(days: 7)),
          firstDate: new DateTime(2015),
          lastDate: new DateTime(2030)
      );
      if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
          print(picked);
      }
    },
    child: new Text("Pick date range")
)
```

[image]

Ref : [date_range_picker 1.0.5](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/date_range_picker)

Comment: Why cant I choose date by tapping on the year?